# How to share language resources with front and back

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have added localization in my project following this doc :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-2.2

It works as expected but I am facing an issue. Sometimes I need to display modal windows (to confirm logout request for example) but I haven't found yet the best way to handle it with language resources.

I tried by using javascript to create those modals but I did not find a clean way to share the resource files with the javascript.

I also tried using partial views but the only solution I found is to use an Ajax request to retrieve the view from the server. At first sight I thought my problem was solved but I realized that if my view could not be retrieved from the server I would not be able to display an error message in the right language as my javascript does not have access to the resource files.

I was wondering what would be the best way to proceed. I hope my explanations are as clear as needed.

Thank you for your help

Comment: You can and you have to implemt the logic to read the localize file in Frontend side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The framework provides a way to use resource in the view ([this part of the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-2.2#view-localization)), so what you can do is to have your modal windows hidden by default in the html and use javascript to toggle their visibility when needed.

All resource strings will be replaced when the view is rendered so no need to make server calls to get them.

So something like that:

The view

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization

@inject IViewLocalizer Localizer

// html of the view

<div id="error_modal" class="modals">
    <span>@Localizer["The error message"]</span>
</div>
```

With the css rule

```css
.modals
{
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

And then use javascript to show or hide the div (just an example, the way of doing this depends on the javasript library you're using).

Hope it's clear and and that's what you need.